# R: proto: gwidgets: RGtk2

Tags: r

I'd like to ask you how can we bind gwidgets and RGtk2 under proto.
For example we have the following two objects.
w1 is created with gwidgets and w2 is created with RGtk2:

```
w1 <- gwindow()
w2 <- gtkWindowNew(type = NULL, show = TRUE)
```

How can we bind them under proto or
how one could be the parent of the other ?

Tnank you in advance

Comment: @jverzani: Thank you very much. Looking forward for your book "Programming Graphical User Interfaces with R".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing would be to work with RGtk2 objects. These can be returned by getToolkitWidget. For example something like this might be what you want:

```
gtk_w1 <- getToolkitWidget(w1)
w2$setTransientFor(gtk_w1)
w2$SetPosition(GtkWindowPosition["center-on-parent"])
w2$SetDestroyWithParent(TRUE)
```